# htaccess regex return Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new to apache & php world and I struggle with .htaccess redirections.
Here is what I want to do:
people of trust will have access to a dedicated directory in */members*.

```
/ => index.php
/<user> => /members/<user>/index.{php,html}
/<user>/... => /members/<user>/...
/<user>/reload = > index.php?reload=<user>
```

Directory layout:

```
- index.php
- .htaccess
- members/
  - <user1>/
    - member's html/php
  - <user2>/
```

What I've done so far (not working):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.exemple\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.subdomain.exemple.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.exemple\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.subdomain.exemple.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

# [a-z]+ is member's username
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/reload/$ index.php?reload=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/reload$ index.php?reload=$1 [L]


#ROOT (I don't know how to redirect to php or html depending on which file exists)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ members/$1/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ members/$1/index.php [L]

#Every other URL excluding / and /<user>/reload
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ members/$1 [L]
```

I also want to "isolate" members' directory by prohibiting php scripts to access parent directories. I've found this but does it mean I should write a rule for each member's directory?

```
<Directory /parentDirectory/childDirectoryOne>
 php_admin_value open_basedir "/parentDirectory/childDirectoryOne"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can _read_ what causes the internal error instead of having to _guess_ ...

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, it says `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error`.  It also says I've got to use `LogLevel debug`. I assume it can be done with htaccess, so I'll have a deeper look into this later

Comment: So you have an endless redirection loop.

Comment: Indeed: the last rewriting rule you implemented will certainly result in an endless rewriting loop: the pattern matches the target again. So it will rewrite to `/members/members/members/members/members/...` Please understand that the old `[L]` flag terminates _the current run_ of the rewriting engine, not the rewriting process itself. Since the rule changes the request another run is started right away which again gets rewritten...

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to get it work.
To avoid the loop mentioned by @arkascha, I added a negative lookahead `(?!members)`. But at the website's root, index.php was redirected to /members/index.php. So I append a second negative lookahead `(?!index.php)`. 
The last struggle was that exemple.com/user was redirected to exemple.com/members/user. Couldn't resolve this one on purpose, but it works. Here is the final code :

```
RewriteRule ^(?:members)?([a-z]+)/reload/?$ index.php?reload=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!members)(?!index.php)(.+)$ members/$1 [L]
```

Concerning the "isolation" of member's directories, I still have no solution.